# mongodb geoNear command with filter

Tags: php, mongodb

I've come across some issues when using mongodb's geoNear command with an additional query to filter the results. The following queries are made with rockmongo.

In my collection "poi", documents have "profiles", which is an array containing objectids. When searching for them :

```
{
  geoNear : "poi",
  near : [19,47],
  query : {profiles : ObjectId("511f360901c610e813000004")}
}
```

I get no result.

```
Response from server: {    "ns": "local.poi",    "near": "1100010010100011101101101111001010100011101101101111",    "results": [
        ],    "stats": {
     "time": NumberInt(2),
     "btreelocs": NumberInt(0),
     "nscanned": NumberInt(510),
     "objectsLoaded": NumberInt(510),
     "avgDistance": 0,
     "maxDistance": 0    },    "ok": 1  }
```

However, without the query, or even with a simple {profiles : ObjectId("511f360901c610e813000004")} query I get the expected results.

Another issue is when I have approximately half of the documents with "name" "x", and the other half with "y", the query

```
{
  geoNear : "poi",
  near : [47,19.5],
  query : {"$and" : [{name : { "$in" : [/.*y.*/i]}}]}
}
```

gives no results, when the simple   {"$and" : [{name : { "$in" : [/.*y.*/i]}}]} gives them. This example query in fact can be much simple, though there's no difference regarding the results, and this is more like my actual queries in the project.

When I try these with PHP, I get results regardless of the additional query being passed, so every document sorted by distance.

Please help me find out if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Of course, other filtering queries like {name : "x"} work perfectly, I am struggling with these "more complex" ones.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was with the PHP driver. I discovered that it works in the mongo shell, so I switched back to 1.3.1, and now it works!

Comment: It's unlikely the PHP driver was at fault here. There is no special processing for [MongoDB::command()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php) arguments and results.