# NodeJs : $nin array query in $geoNear in MongoDb doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I don't understand why my query doesn't work with MongoDb $geoNear ?

I checked this issue without success : [mongodb geoNear command with filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939698/mongodb-geonear-command-with-filter)

My environment :

- NodeJs : V6.6.0
- Mongoose : 4.8.6

**this works**

```
db.collection.geoNear(
  coords,
  {
  query : { status: "1" } }, // I have the good filtered results
  ...
```

**I already tested**

```
...
query : { _id: { $in: itemIds } }, //no error and empty result
query : { "_id": "5639ce8c01f7d527089d2a74" },  //no error and empty result
query : { "_id" : 'ObjectId("5649e9f35f0b360300cad022")' }, //no error and empty result
query : { "_id" : ObjectId("5649e9f35f0b360300cad022") }, //error ObjectId not defined
...
```

**I want this**

```
db.collection.geoNear(
  coords,
  {
  query : { _id: { $nin: poiIds } }, // no error but I have not the good results because I obtain all results geolocalized
  ...
```

**Thank you ;-)**

Answer (score 0):

For this issue:

> query : { "_id" : ObjectId("5649e9f35f0b360300cad022") }, //error ObjectId not defined

Try:

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did it like this:

Add index to coords in your model, then request with query.

```
modelSchema.index({ coords: '2dsphere' });

query = {
  _id: {
    $nin: poiIds
  },
  coords: {
    $near: {
      $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: position }
    }
  }
}
```

where `position` is an array `[Lat, Lon]`.

Hope this helps. ;)